# Using Glimpse in asp.net core RTM web api

Tags: asp.net-core, glimpse, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using ASP.NET Core Web API, and I have installed the beta2 version of Glimpse for profiling. I was able to do `services.AddGlimpse` and `app.UseGlimpse` in Startup.cs, but Glimpse HUD is not showing up in the Browser when I am firing the API end points.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you tried standalone view? You can check like this- `http://localhost:port/Glimpse.axd`

Comment: Are you referring to Glimpse v2 beta or some other Glimpse beta2?

Comment: Have you been able to make it work with controller actions that return a view?

Comment: i tried accessing the .axd file file.but i am getting 404.

Comment: The library that i am talking about is "Glimpse": "2.0.0-beta2-201607261439".This working fine with asp.net core web app returning View.

Comment: It turns out that we need to use the full Glimpse client to inspect API calls.

Answer (score 1):

The Glimpse HUB requires HTML into which to inject itself. Result: the HUB cannot inject itself into an API endpoint that returns plain text or JSON. Instead, we have to use the full Glimpse client. Here is how.

Go to http://localhost:5000 (or to any page that renders the HUB) and click on the "g" link.

[image]

That will open the full Glimpse Client in a new tab.

[image]

Now, return to your original tab and navigate to an API route (e.g. /api/products).

[image]

Return again to the full Glimpse Client to see the analysis of that request.

[image]

See: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Prototype/issues/132

Comment: How do I know which url renders HUB?